# jQuery: clone and cut portion of SVG image on a separate DIV

Tags: jquery, svg, clipping

I have an SVG image defining a red square, an orange circle and a green circle:

[image]

The goal is to show on a separate div a portion/clip of the image (from pixel 50,50 to 100,100 for example to highlight only the area of green circle) with a zoom factor but I don't know how to reassign the 'viewBox' values:

```
<svg width='200' height='200' id='main' viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
  <rect x='10' y='10' width='80' height='80' fill='red'></rect>
  <circle cx='25' cy='25' r='25' fill='orange'></circle>
  <circle cx='75' cy='75' r='25' fill='green'></circle>
</svg>
<div id='portion'></div>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ab2erd4q/2/)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
svgclone = $('#main').clone();

svgclone.width(50);
svgclone.height(50);
$('#portion').html(svgclone);
</script>
```

Are there any trick or workaround to show a specific portion (not starting from origin 0,0) of native SVG on a separate container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery `.attr()` converts attribute names to lowercase, making `viewbox` out of `viewBox`. Use the generic `.setAttribute()` instead:

```
svgclone.get(0).setAttribute('viewBox', '50 50 50 50')
```